# get all files excluding one folder

Tags: powershell

I've looked at some other questions on here regarding this but I don't get it. I want to get all .less files in my solution and compile them into a single file.

It worked great thanks to an answer on here but i discovered I need to ignore the folder 'OBJ' and its sub folders.

I tried this based on answers here but no dice. Any ideas?

```
ls $dirPath -r -I *.less | ? { $_psiscontainer -and $_.fullname -notmatch 'obj' } 
| gc | sc -enc UTF8 $dirPath\Styles\CompiledLESS.less
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Where-Object filter, you've specified $_.psiscontainter.  This means you are keeping just the directory objects and discarding all the file objects.

Comment: I'm a total powershell noob so I have no idea what I am doing. I only need it for this one task so I haven't had chance to learn it. Im just hacking examples i find on my phone. When the internet comes back up I'll do some research around this thanks.

Comment: Simply removing that fixed it. I'm not sure it is perfect because it might match a file called abcOBJdef.less but it works for now.

Comment: You can use $_.fullname -notmatch '\\obj\\' to insure it just excludes files in that directory.